# How to pass dynamically rendered content to binding handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, selectize.js

I've a select tag and a custom binding handler(**sample**) on it. when I've static options I see all the option tags(**element**) at custom binding handler but when we dynamically render options how can I get the same

case 1:

```
<select data-bind="sample:{}">
    <option value="">Select gear...</option>
    <option value="pitons">Pitons</option>
    <option value="cams">Cams</option>
</select>
```

case 2:

```
<select data-bind="sample:{},foreach:options">
    <option data-bind="text:optValue"></option>
</select>
```

Code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sample = {
    init: function (element) {
     case 1: element has all 3 options
     case 2: element has **nothing** as <option> is rendered dynamically
 }
}
```

Actually I'm trying to add **selectize** to the element, as in case 2 as no options rendered i'm not able to apply the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom binding handler function takes 5 parameters:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.sample = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var options = allBindings.get('options');
        console.log(options);
    }
};
```

The third parameter you can use to access all model values bound to the element using its `get` method. So, that means you can do this: `allBindings.get('options')` and that should give you access to the dynamic select options.

You will probably want to use the `update` callback for your binding handler instead of `init`, since your options are dynamic and may arrive after the select element has been initialized.